# Is this easy matrix diagonalizable or not?

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question**

Is

$$
\pmatrix{
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
}
$$

diagonalizable

- if we allow only real numbers?
- if we allow complex numbers?

**Attempt**

Sure, I could go ahead and compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors, and iff the eigenvectors are linearly independent, then I would be able to invert $S$. But is there an easier way to see this?

Comment: That isn't much of an attempt.

Comment: This is the [companion matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of $x^4-1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy to calculate the characteristic polynomial $$\chi_A(x)=\det
\pmatrix{
-x & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & -x & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & -x & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -x
}
$$
by developing along the last column so we find
$$\chi_A(x)=x^4-1$$
so its roots are the $4$-th roots of $1$ which are different so $A$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: Appendix: diagonalizable over $\mathbb C$, not $\mathbb R$ (so the first answer is *no*, the second is *yes*).

Comment: is it not in **R** because we have *dependent* eigenvectors?

Comment: No because the eigenvalues are not real.@jacob

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix represents an element of the symmetric group $S_4$. It's orthogonal and therefore diagonalizable.

Comment: Never heard "symmetric group $S_4$".

Comment: The matrix is unitary, which implies that all of its eigenvalues lie on the unit circle.  Moreover, the eigenvalues are the $4$ distinct $4$-th roots of unity, which implies that the algebraic multiplicity of each eigenvalue equals its geometric multiplicity.  Hence, the matrix is indeed diagonalizable.

Comment: @MustafaSaid, you could stop after "...roots of unity.", since then it is clear the matrix is a $\;4\times 4\;$ one with $\;4\;$ *different* eigenvalues and thus automatically diagonalizable. No need to get into alg. and geom. multiplicities.

Comment: @jacob see [here](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Symmetric_group:S4)...

Comment: @MustafaSaid ["The real analogue of a unitary matrix is an orthogonal matrix."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix)